# Jetpack Compose Text and Image get overlapped inside Column layout issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack-compose-column

I am using `Jetpack Compose` for designing dynamic Layout inside android app. `Column` layout is used to place elements like `Vertical` layout. This kind of behaviour is achieved using `LinearLayout` orientation `Vertical` usage without compose. Inside Column I have added one `Image` on top and one text I want to display below it. But after placing the Text inside the Compose `Column` layout it is getting overlapped. How to resolve this.
The code for adding `Image` and `Text` is as follows

```
@Composable
fun GreetingSectionExperimental(
    name: String = "Philipp"
) {
    //var text by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Image(
            painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(80.dp).offset(0.dp,35.dp),
            alignment = Alignment.Center,
            contentDescription = ""
        )
        Text(
            text = "Login / Sign Up",
            Modifier.padding(10.dp).align(CenterHorizontally),
            color = textColor, fontSize = 18.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
        )
    }
}
```

I am getting output as
[image]

How to resolve this ? Inside the current what is missing or `Column` does not support different kind of elements.

Comment: Why do you need this offset on your image? That's the reason why it overlaps

Comment: To show image some a little below from top. How to push Image little down from top, if I wish to remove offset as you said ??

Comment: For this you should use `padding` (either bottom on your `Image` modifier or top on your `Text`)

Comment: But this will reduce and push Image inside layout and Image will get small. What say ?

Comment: Figured it out. Can use `Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))` to create space. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: It depends where you call `padding` :) If that's after the `height` modifier, then yes because it treats it as padding instead of margin – if you're familiar with these terms before compose. But `Spacer ` is fine too ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the property "Offset" from your image
the code should looks like

```
@Composable
fun GreetingSectionExperimental(
    name: String = "Philipp"
) {
    //var text by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Image(
            painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(80.dp), //Remove the offset here
            alignment = Alignment.Center,
            contentDescription = ""
        )
        Text(
            text = "Login / Sign Up",
            Modifier.padding(10.dp).align(CenterHorizontally),
            color = textColor, fontSize = 18.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Result here]

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use `Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))`. It will create space between the those Elements this in between this is added.